# If $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal random variables and $X$ is decomposed into orthogonal components, can $Y$ be non-orthogonal to each of the components?

Tags: statistics

Let's say $E[XY] = 0$ ($X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal).

If we decompose X into two orthogonal components $X_r$ and $X_n$ (any such decomposition), is it possible for both $E[X_rY] \neq 0$ and $E[X_nY]\neq 0$? In other words, $Y$ is not orthogonal to each of these components, yet orthogonal to $X$.

So far I've shown that this can be true when $Y$ is equal to a constant, but I can't seem to understand under what conditions it would be true for a more complicated $Y$.

Comment: If you have a construction for $X,X_r,X_n$ that works when $Y$ is a constant, my hunch is that the same construction would work when $Y$ is independent of $X$ in general. What is your construction?

Comment: Let's say Y = 1. X and Z are random variables such that E[X] = 0 and E[Z] = c, where c is a nonzero constant. Thus E[XY] = 0.  Find the linear projection of X onto Z. Then we have X = Z*b+ e, where b is the coef resulting from the linear projection and e is orthogonal to Z*b by definition. However, we have E[Z*b] does not equal zero ( as long as b is not zero, which we will assume ). Then we have E[Z*b*Y] does not equal zero.

Comment: Your comment made me think perhaps it is possible. Let's generalize Y to a r.v. with E[Y] = d, a nonzero constant. Now assume Y is independent to both X and Z. Following the above example, we also have E[XY] = 0. We also then we have E[YZb] = nonzero constant. This seems valid to show that the answer to the question in my title is yes. What do you think? If you can offer any comments or further insights about conditions under which this is true it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since this is actually basic Euclidean geometry, one can be sure that the following works: $X=U+V$, $Y=U-V$, $X_r=U$, $X_n=V$, $(U,V)$ i.i.d. centered.